# No detener aplicación cuando se bloquee pantalla (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xamarin.android

Tengo una aplicación en Xamarin Android que tiene un thread el cual hace un trabajo mientras la app está abierta, este thread está haciendo operaciones con un HttpClient, pero al bloquear el celular la app deja de procesar lo que hacía e inmediatamente me salta una excepción de que el socket se ha cerrado.

Quisiera saber como lograr que la app siga trabajando al estar el celular bloqueado con la misma normalidad que hace cuando no está bloqueado.

Comment: no uso nunca Xamarin.Android, pero tenes que hacer como un Service, en lugar de Activity a una clase la decoras como Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente logré resolver este problema creando un servicio y usando WakeLock para que no se detenga el servicio cuando se bloquee el celular